# jquery handlers/data recreating after dom destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

It looks like in jQuery after the element is destroyed, all jQuery-related data is being destroyed - including values saved with data(), all event handlers etc. However, the dom itself is preserved and can be used again. I wonder whether it is possible to retrieve this data in any easy way, or do I have to save it myself somehow and recreate it?

Simple example written in jquery: http://jsbin.com/examuh/2/edit . You can see the effect at http://jsbin.com/examuh/2 . As you can see, only the third handler works, which is added after reappending is working - even the one added after destroy, but before reappending is not working. Apparently, the DOM along with the #id is preserved.

PS: My real example is more complex, and remaking it to move the dom element to a safe place before destroying parent will be probably quite much of a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain the event handlers and jquery data etc, you can use the jQuery method [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove the elements from the DOM. You can then re-insert it back into the DOM tree at a later date using the standard .append() / .prepend() etc methods.

If you use .remove() then the jQuery data is deleted. Your example seems to demonstrate that setting the html() property of a div has a similar effect to using .remove() in jQuery on the child elements of the div.

```
var keepThis = $("#toRemove").detach();
//.. later on
$("#insert-point").append(keepThis);
```

Comment: Thanks, it explained what's happening. As I did not know at the point of the removal which child elements might be needed later, I store my data somewhere else stored identified by a dom id and reattach it later when needed.